# Are there any browser add-ons for debugging Javascript with Visual Studio (2013)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

When I was using WebStorm with Chrome add-on, I was able to debug my javascript code quite easily.
On my current project I need to use Visual Studio 2013, and I wander if there are any viable aids to do integrated debugging. What I'm looking for is to be able to set the break points, and have the VS stop at those points when they are hit in a browser.
What are the good options to achieve such experience (beside using the "debug" keyword in the code)?

Comment: If you launch Internet Explorer as your browser that is exactly what will happen by default...

Comment: You can debug from VS only if you launch it with IE. I find Chrome's devtools and Firebug are nicer to debug JavaScript than VS.

Comment: Wow, Firefox is a LOT nicer when dealing with Javascript! How do I mark your comment as the answer?